# XSL transformation using Java: number format issue

Tags: java, transform, xslt-1.0, xslt

I have JDK6 and using JAXP for the transformation. I am beginner to XSLT.

Source XML:

```
<Number>
    <Value>529.82</Value>
</Number>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Number">
        <xsl:element name="Result">
            <xsl:element name="Total">
                <xsl:attribute name="Amount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Value, '#.00')*100"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
     <Total Amount="52982.00000000001"/>
</Result>
```

Here the value of `Amount` attribue should be 52982.
Please help.

Comment: Java is a word and not an abbreivation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Number">
     <Result>
      <Total amount="{round(format-number(Value, '#.00')*100)}"/>
     </Result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Number>
    <Value>529.82</Value>
</Number>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Result>
   <Total amount="52982"/>
</Result>
```

**Explanation**:

XSLT 1.0 has only a single numeric type, and it is the *double* type.

As with any floating point type, there are precision errors.

In XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0 one can use the `xs:decimal` type, so that any precision errors are eliminated -- of course, the `xs:decimal` type has a defined maximum number of digits.

---

**For reference, here is the corresponding XSLT 2.0 transformation using `xs:decimal`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Number">
     <Result>
      <Total amount="{xs:decimal(format-number(Value, '#.00'))*100}"/>
     </Result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<Result>
   <Total amount="52982"/>
</Result>
```

**Or even simpler (without `format-number()`):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Number">
     <Result>
      <Total amount="{xs:decimal(Value)*100}"/>
     </Result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's actually no need to do the `format-number` at all then, just `<Total amount="{round(Value*100)}"/>` would work, surely?

Comment: @IanRoberts, Yes, but we don't know the actual context -- the OP may have some reason of using it.

Comment: @IanRoberts: I need to first convert into 2 decimal value that's why

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Value*100, '#')"/>
```

The problem with your previous approach is that you're formatting the `Value` to a string, then converting it back to a number and multiplying it by 100.  You need to do the multiplication on the original number and then format the result.

Comment: @joergl I copied your original format pattern initially, I've now edited my answer to a more appropriate pattern.

Comment: Seen that, and deleted my comment before I saw yours. Too much parallelism ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `round()` function. Simply wrap your `format-number()` call in it. The following stylesheet does the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Number">
        <xsl:element name="Result">
            <xsl:element name="Total">
                <xsl:attribute name="Amount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="round(format-number(Value, '#.00')*100)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```